# Get HTML Module Contents by Module ID in DNN

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-7

I'm developing a custom module in C# and would like to get the contents of an HTML module that is located in the site to display as part of my module.  How can I go about getting the html contents.  For instance, if I had a module with an ID of 746 I would like to call it with something similar:

```
var objModule = new ModuleControler();
var myModule = ModuleControler.GetModuleContentsByID(746);
myLabel.text = myModule.html;
```

Is there a way to do this?  All the classes that I have reviewed seem to be deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the controller classes from the Html module:

DotNetNuke.Modules.Html.HtmlTextController.GetAllHtmlText(int ModuleID)

etc.

As the Html module supports workflow there might be more than one record per module.